# Tell Vim to complete ':sp<TAB>' to ':split' instead of ':spelldump'

Tags: vim

In Vim, whenever I want to open a file additional to the currently open file(s), I use

```
:split (or :vsplit)
```

I do this by typing `:sp<TAB>`. In Vim6 this used to complete to `:split`. These days VIm7 is installed everywhere by default, and it completes to `:sp<TAB>` to `:spelldump`. I know I could type `:spl<TAB>`, but you know, muscle memory.

Is there some way I can tell VIm to give precedence to `:split`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't use <kbd>tab</kbd>:

```
:sp .vimrc
```

Then you will split. [`:sp`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#%3asp) is the same as [`:split`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#%3asplit).

Confirmed in v7.3.286.

If you (or your muscle memory) really want to type:

```
:sp<tab>
```

Then you could create a mapping with [`:cnoremap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3acnoremap):

```
:cnoremap sp<tab> split<space>
```

Comment: No clue why I never figured out that :sp is the same as :split! Thx.